# Silverlight 4 default value for dependency property using the default value of another dependency property

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, dependency-properties, default-value

I am trying to use the default value of the textblock's property for a control by using:

```
 public static readonly DependencyProperty FontFamilyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                             "FontFamily", typeof(FontFamily), typeof(IMTextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(TextBlock.TextProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(FontFamily)).DefaultValue));
```

I am getting this error:

```
  The invocation of the constructor on type 'Common.Infrastructure.Controls.IMTextBlock' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.
```

What is the right way to do this?

```
 TextBlock.TextProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(FontFamily)).DefaultValue
```

is not getting me the correct default value, or maybe I am not using it correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type you pass to `GetMetaData` is the not the property type, its the owner type.  Hence you should be using:-

```
 TextBlock.FontFamilyProperty.GetMetadata(typeof(TextBlock)).DefaultValue
```